# Is it possible to specify query parameters in Yesod routes?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to specify queries in a rest-like manner in my yesod routes, e.g.

```
mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
/first/?count=#Int FirstR GET
/second/?count=#Int SecondR GET
|]
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
The function `FirstR' is applied to one argument,
but its type `Route HelloYesod' has none
```

But if I push that `#Int` back to being part of the path, it is all fine. I assume this is because the route isn't generated with a parameter?

Is there a way for me to specify that parameter in my route?

Comment: It is not REST! (and Yesod is REST) :D Why not simply "/first/count/#Int"? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not possible with the current setup, though it's an addition I've considered making in the past. The main reasons I haven't is (1) it would probably make the normal case a bit difficult to achieve, and (2) as josejuan mentions, it's often (though not always) possible to convert this into a route-based parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's not a problem for me to push those back into the URI, I was just curious (and walking down the rabbit hole).